# Special characters in static resource

Tags: javascript, developer-console, static-resources, locale, character-encoding

The nordic characters æøå are displayed as question marks in JS static resource after reopening the file in the Developer Console. An alert box with these characters will also display as question marks.

How to save Javascript Static Resources as UTF-8?

Comment: Hi. I know that you can save files with UTF-8 encoding on Notepad++.

Comment: Developer console is not the best place to edit static resources, either use download and edit in notepad++ as suggested by @MartinLezer; or use [`Mavensmate`](http://www.joe-ferraro.com/2012/12/mavensmate-resource-bundles/) which is by far the best method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default notepad in Windows to change the encoding to UTF-8. Please refer this Salesforce [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003837&type=1) describing how to change CSV encoding. But this is same for any text based files. Refere to point 8 and 9.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While using Mavensmate / Sublime, instead of saving a static resource by clicking on 'Save' or Ctrl + S, Please go to File Menu -> Save with encoding -> UTF-8

[image: Screenshot of the same below]